# Partial differential equation : $z_x+z_y+z=e^{x+2y},z(x,0)=0$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

> How to solve this equation:
>   $$z_x+z_y+z=e^{x+2y}$$ with boundary condition as $z(x,0)=0$

I tried $$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{e^{x+2y}-z}$$
I got one condition as 
$y-x=a$ how to obtain other constant condition.?
can you please help ? How to fix that extra z or exponential term rid of dz, I felt we should use some mulitplier tricks ?

Comment: If you know that $y - x = c_{1}$, then $e^{x+2y} \equiv e^{3x + c_{1}}$ (or $\equiv e^{3y - c_{1}}$) and hence $$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dz}{e^{x+2y}-z} \implies \frac{dz}{dx} = e^{3x+c_{1}}-z$$ which is easily solved.

Comment: See also this same task with a different question in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239501/115115

Answer (score 2):

Solution of $z_x+z_y+z=0$ is $$z_h=e^{-x}f(y-x)$$

Particular solution of $z_x+z_y+z=e^{x+2y}$  is 
$$ z_p=\frac{e^{x+2y}}{4}$$
Then general solution is
$$z=z_h+z_p=e^{-x}f(y-x)+\frac{e^{x+2y}}{4}$$

Final solution with initial condition $z(x,0)=0$ is
$$z=\frac{e^{x+2y}}{4}-\frac{e^{x-2y}}{4}=\frac12e^x\sinh(2y)$$

Comment: You might want to explain the reasoning for your ansatz for the particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using $r=\frac ab=\frac cd\implies r=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ gives as second relation
$$
\frac{dx+2dy}{1+2}=\frac{dz}{e^{x+2y}-z}
$$
so that with $r=x+2y$ we get 
$$
\frac{dz}{dr}=\frac{e^r-z}3
\\
\frac{d}{dr}(e^{r/3}z)=\frac{e^{4r/3}}3
\\
e^{r/3}z=c_2+\frac{e^{4r/3}}4
$$
so that going back to the general procedure with $c_2=\phi(c_1)$ it follows that
$$
z=\phi(y-x)e^{-(x+2y)/3}+\frac14e^{x+2y}
$$
Now insert the initial condition
$$
0=z(-x,0)=\phi(x)e^{x/3}+\frac14e^{-x}\implies \phi(x)=-\frac14 e^{-4x/3}
$$
and combine to get the solution to this specific problem.